# XStream double underline handling (Java)

Tags: java, xstream, underline

I wanted to serialize a java class to XML with XStream.

I needed to generated an XML element with one underline (canal_operateur), but XStream adds a second underline in the xml element name.

**So how to keep only one underline ?**

With the default configuration for this class :

```
public class Document implements Serializable {
    private String typedoc;
    private Fichier fichier;
    private String canalOperateur;  
    //xstream.aliasField("canal_operateur", Document.class, "canalOperateur");
    /*
    ** setter and getter
    */
}
```

XStream doubles the underline :

```
<document>
    <canal__operateur>canal</canal__operateur>
    <commentaire>commentaire</commentaire>
    <metadonnees/>
</document>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [here](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#XML_double_underscores):

> XStream maps Java class names and field names to XML tags or
>   attributes. Unfortunately this mapping cannot be 1:1, since some
>   characters used for identifiers in Java are invalid in XML names.
>   Therefore XStream uses an XmlFriendlyNameCoder to replace these
>   characters with a replacement. By default this NameCoder uses an
>   underscore as escape character and has therefore to escape the
>   underscore itself also. You may provide a different configured
>   instance of the XmlFriendlyNameCoder or a complete different
>   implementation like the NoNameCoder to prevent name coding at all.
>   However it is your responsibility then to ensure, that the resulting
>   names are valid for XML.